# UITableView - footer of last section scrolls off the bottom of the screen. How to prevent?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I have a **grouped** UITableView.  I've implemented **tableView(*:titleForHeaderInSection:)*** and **tableView(:titleForFooterInSection:)**.  As I scroll a long table, I can see that the section headers and footers contain the expected data.  When I get to the bottom of the table and I drag up to see the footer of the last section, it has the correct data, but when I release my finger, the footer scrolls back down past the bottom of the screen and out of view.  The last cell of the last section is what appears at the bottom of the screen rather than the footer of the last section.

How to fix it?
[There's the last section and its footer.  My finger is still on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cWXL.png)

[When I release my finger, the final footer slides off the bottom of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNvq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix scrolling content issue by considering one of the following methods.

**Method 1:** Natural way to fix your problem by setting up your `tableView` frame and its bottom constraint properly from your storyboard.

**Updated:**

[image: walkthrough of changes]

**Method 2**: You can validate your `tableView` frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!)
 }
```

**Method 3**: Setting up your `tableView` frame by adjusting scroll view `insets`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: I used a TableViewController and couldn't find a way to resize the tableView as shown in the vids (nice touch!).  I poked around a was able to use Method 3 and that seems to work.  One of these days, I'll understand it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's blocked by the tabbar.
If using storyborad, reset the constraint of your tableView.
If not, you need to set the frame of your tableView correctly.

Comment: Make sure the table view's bottom constraint is linked to the `Bottom Layout Guide`, and not the `Container Margin`.

Comment: Ah!  I put no explicit constraints anywhere yet.  But the behind the "tab bar" makes a lot of sense.  I'll pursue that.  Thanks.