# Translucent Status Bar with No Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Goal: To have a table view scroll so that it shows semitransparent under the status bar while not displaying a navigation bar.

Right now, I have my tableView set to the top anchor (so technically underneath the status bar). This sets the status bar to a solid looking color as you scroll up on the table view. I've set the navigationAppearance's barTintColor and translucent to YES with no luck.

Any ideas? The view is instantiated in a storyboard

Comment: I can't tell what you mean. Maybe attach a picture of what you currently have?

Comment: I'll use Apple Music as an example. If you scroll up on the Library tab, you can see the text "Library" opaquely while it is underneath the status bar. I want to do exactly that @DanielLegler

Comment: can you update with `screenshot` of your problem or possibly some code you have tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is hard to guess without any `code`.I believe you trying to achieve a translucent status bar when tableview content scroll like you mentioned in Apple Music app.

Try below code inside your `viewdidLoad` method.

**Step 1:** To hide `navigation bar`. If your `controller` embedded with `navigationController`.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

**Step 2:** Place a statusBar size `UIView` to your controller to act as a translucent status Bar with adjusting `alpha` value.

```
 let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.size.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height))
 statusBarView.backgroundColor=UIColor.white 
 statusBarView.alpha = 0.8 // set any value between 0 to 1
 view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Above code will produce the following output.Let me know the code works for you.

[image]

For more information how to set `tableView frame` and `contentView` take a look at my answer in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105065/uitableview-footer-of-last-section-scrolls-off-the-bottom-of-the-screen-how-t/43106524#43106524).

---

**Update:**

**Improved Answer:**

You can use `UIBlurEffectView` to achieve better translucent effect.

```
    let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.size.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height))
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight) // Set any style you want(.light or .dark) to achieve different effect.
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = statusBarView.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    statusBarView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you described, your `UITableView` is right underneath the status bar. When you scroll down, the `tableView`'s frame remains the same size and origin and won't go underneath the status bar. What you want to do is to set the constraint for your `tableView` to the top of the superview (not the Top Layout Guide) which means it would sit right under the status bar.

Because the status bar now hides the top 20px of your `tableView` you want to make a content offset:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

To make the scroll indicator start right under the status bar you also want to set an offset for it:

```
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your response! that makes sense, however, when I do that, I see the contents of the UITableView overlap with the status bar. The scroll indicator does not stop at the status bar either but overlaps as well. Any ideas why that might be @Codey ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with overlapping. The because you set the `contentInset` cells should all have a little bit of offset, so that when you scroll to the top of your tableView, you should not have any overlapping. I edited my answer regarding the scroll indicator.