# UIStatusBar Translucent Style

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I've mentioned some new trends in "Segue-Navigation" paradigm from Apple.
In apps like Apple Music, Health or News all main "start-point" controllers do not have navigation bar. Instead - there is a big bold beautiful title.
I'd like to do the same in my app.
I created UITableViewController with static cells. The first one contains title of controller.

But when I scroll up, status bar merges with this cell, so I want this cell to be behind of status bar like in Apple apps.

[image: My UITableViewontroller]

[image: VC and Status bar conflict]

[image: Apple's solution]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191161/translucent-status-bar-with-no-navigation-bar/43239071#43239071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.size.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height))
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = statusBarView.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
statusBarView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(statusBarView)
```