# Changing alpha value of navigationbar so underlying objects are visible

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to implement a translucent NavigationBar so underlying objects are visible.

It should look like here:

[image]

This view is a custom view which uses alpha value to achieve the translucency behavior.

I tried this to implement my custom NavigationBar like this:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(netHex: CxtColor.black.rawValue)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().inputView?.alpha = 0.4
    UINavigationBar.appearance().alpha = 0.4
```

But its not translucent and also the changing of the alpha value has no really effect on the NavigationBar. Its just a white navigationbar.

I don't want to create a full transparent navigationbar.

Comment: check the following posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419860/how-can-i-get-the-color-and-translucency-of-the-ios-10-watch-navigation-bar/43527133#43527133 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191161/translucent-status-bar-with-no-navigation-bar/43239071#43239071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

]you can access navigationBackgroundView

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        let navigationBackgroundView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first
        navigationBackgroundView?.alpha = 0.3
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution in viewWillAppear function but still no effect. Just a white view with back button

Comment: @Kingalione see attached image UIbutton under navigation controller

Comment: @Kingalione  check attached image

Comment: @Kingalione are it work with you or you face problem

Comment: nope sitll not working. what did you set up for the navigationBar in storyboard?